# Can I tie 2 agents at once?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to make 2 Jenkins agents do the same job at the same time.

2 agent's label is same:'rs'.

Project setting is "Restrict where this project can be run" selected Label Expression 'rs'.

When I click build now button, only one of the agents is working.

Is this normal? Is there a way to distribute one job to multiple agents at one click?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicates:  [Jenkins - How to run one housekeeping job on all nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64729773/598141), [Running Jenkins job simultaneously on all nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17286614/598141). Also, they are called agents, not slaves.

Comment: It looks you are asking about parallelization for a build . See if this link is helpful https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

Comment: Great!! Thanks for help all of you!!